# Unable to reach DEIS controller on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, deis

I'm following the official guide for installing deis on google cloud.
Everything worked fine except the fact that now I'm not able to register users to the platform (which is up and running).
When I give the following command:

```
./deis register http://deis.mydeisdemo.io
```

it gives

```
Make sure that the Controller URI is correct and the server is running.
Error: Get http://deis.mydeisdemo.io/v1/: dial tcp: lookup deis.mydeisdemo.io on 169.254.169.254:53: no such host
```

In simple words I don't know how to reach the deis controller and I'm not sure the DNS are working fine. 
How can I solve?

Comment: I'm quite sure the DNS are not working since I cannot ping "deis.mydeisdemo.io" or "mydeisdemo.io" but I can ping the IP on which mydeisdemo.io points.
ps the command on the IP on which I can ping gives the same output.

Comment: How did you set up DNS? Did you follow http://docs.deis.io/en/latest/installing_deis/gce/#configure-dns? If you use `dig deis.mydeisdemo.io` from your machine, do you see the cloud instances in the answer section as A records?

Another alternative method to try is via xip.io. http://deis.ip_addr.xip.io should resolve to the controller, assuming a router is running on that node.